# Internet (Wi-Fi) acting up on 2 Windows machines

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have a Lenovo machine running Windows 10 Home, and an HP machine running Windows 10 Pro, and I'm facing a weird issue on both the machines.

- Both machines are getting ~30Mbps, whereas my phone is getting ~120Mbps
- Whenever I am on a Google Meet or a Zoom call, I keep getting frozen

I've tried reinstalling Windows and the speeds were back up to 120Mbps for about a week or so, with the calls seeming to be working just fine, but then the speeds went down to 30Mbps and the calls started having issues once again. I also tried switching off Windows Defender Firewall, but it didn't seem to help, and `ping` shows normal return rates.

Could any software be causing this issue? Software that is usually always open:

- Tableau 10.5
- SQL Workbench/J
- Google Chrome
- Jupyter Notebook
- PuTTY

Comment: Is your phone using 5G whereas the PC's are only connecting to 2G? Alot of factors, mirrors can even have an effect.

Comment: More information about the network hardware and your Internet connection would help. The fact that the reinstall changed behavior might point to software,  What happens when all applications are shut down? Have you checked for background app?  Task Manager would help.  Performance tab in Task Manager would show Ethernet traffic. If all applications are shut down and still traffic, there is a possible issue.  Your router software may also show you traffic by computer/app

Comment: On the router, are the radios set to actual channels or Auto? If the latter, they need to be set to channels (2.4GHz: `1`, `6`, or `11`; 5GHz: `157` (US), else highest DFS channel available). Have you updated the drivers for the WiFi cards on the two PCs, and have you configured the properties of those cards (`Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` > Right-click WiFi adapter > Properties > Configure > Advanced _(or similar, Intel's options are under Advanced, but Broadcom and others may not be)_)? For Google Meet/Zoom calls, configure QOS on the router for that traffic.